# Is the empty set is a subspace of any vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the empty set is a subspace of any vector space?

im not too sure about this one, is the zero vector in the empty set?

Comment: As you say, the empty set does not contain the zero vector, and so it is not a vector space.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is no. The empty set is empty in the sense that it does not contain any elements. Thus the zero vector is not a member of the empty set.