# Why is the empty set considered a subspace if it doesn't contain the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $S\subseteq U$ where $S = \emptyset$ and $U$ a vector space. Why is $S$ a subspace automatically if it doesn't contain the zero vector. I understand that it satisfies the other two properties to be a subspace, but the zero vector just doesn't fit.

EDIT:

My inquiry came from the following problem whose proof is stated as below:

If V is a vector space and S a subset of V then the span of S is a subspace of V.

Beginning of proof: if S is the empty set then this is clear.....

My thoughts: however if $S$ is empty then the span of S is also empty..... so the empty set is a subspace what????

Comment: @Mason The OP said sub*space*, not sub*set*. A subspace is more than just a subset of a vector space.

Comment: I've never seen the emptyset considered a subspace, for exactly the reason you state. Do you have a source claiming that it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the empty set is a subspace of any vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771258/is-the-empty-set-is-a-subspace-of-any-vector-space)

Comment: @mfl I don't think this is really a duplicate, since the OP's *real* question is why the proof given uses the language that it does.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think you're right.

Answer (score 5):

The proof in your edit is not claiming the empty set is a subspace. It is claiming the [span of the empty set is a subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049031/proof-that-the-span-of-the-empty-set-is-the-0-vector?rq=1) (namely $\{0\}$). So, the original claim still holds even when $S$ is the empty set.

Comment: How can the span of an empty set contain the zero vector?

Comment: I don't see how the span of $\emptyset$ can be $\left\{\vec 0\right\}$. What's the definition of 'span' in that source?

Comment: @daniel This is ultimately a convention about how sums work; see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum#An_example:_empty_linear_combinations). It can be weird at first, but it turns out to be useful (and it's clearly the only reasonable way to define the empty sum; similarly, the empty product is $1$, the union of no sets is the emptyset, and the intersection of no sets is the whole universe).

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum See my comment.

Comment: Ok. I knew the convention in other contexts, but I had never thought about it for vector spaces. Thanks

Comment: @daniel Another definition for $\text{span}(A)$ is "the intersection of all subspaces containing $A$," from which $\text{span}(\varnothing) = \{0\}$ follows immediately.